# textarea output as a logfile

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I would like to get from a textarea input of a html-Site, after pushing a button, to get something like a logfile, that shows me some information, like time of input for each character.

I imagine so that Output in a txt-file:

```
14:42:21:100    H
14:42:21:200    e
14:42:21:300    l
14:42:21:400    l
14:42:21:600    o
14:42:23:200    [space]
14:42:24:100    W
14:42:24:300    o
14:42:24:500    r
14:42:24:600    l
14:42:24:700    d
14:42:24:900    [enter]
```

It is possible to do that? Maybe someone can give me some tips on how to do this with javascript.
I want to see how long someone needs to enter text.

Answer (score 0):

This code saves the (alphanumeric) key pressed and a date object as a single object into an array, from which you might extract data from later.

```
    var results = [];
$("input").bind("keyup",function(){
  //save the reference to inputbox
  var fn = this;
  results.push({
    //find the last character in the input box value string
    key:fn.value.substr(fn.value.length - 1),
    time: new Date()
  })
  console.log(results);
});
```

However, if you want to simply find out how long someone took to type, this is the code for it:

```
var results = [];
$("input").bind("keyup",function(){
  results.push(new Date())
});
$("button").click(function(){
  console.log(results[results.length-1] - results[0]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but where i have to implement your code?

Comment: I used this code to save the text [link](http://wcetdesigns.com/tutorials/demos/edit-save-file.html)

Comment: You could implement this code:
a) inside <script> tags in an html document
b)  as an external file: <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">

Comment: What exactly didn't work?
Here's a demo demonstrating the code: http://codepen.io/snemvalts/pen/lvtuE

Comment: many thanks for your effort, but the result is that the text file is not reformatted for my needs